# Compiled Classes Missing From Project

Tags: eclipse

I've noticed that randomly when I come back to Eclipse after shutting it down the compiled classes of my projects can't be found.  The resolution is to clean all projects and rebuild.  Its happened with the previous versions of Eclipse also.  Any idea why this happens and can I shut it down?

Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

Comment: This is interesting.  The problem happened again and external jars for a framework were missing in the below folder.  Eclipse correctly reported it couldn't find the classes contained within the jars.  I did a complete clean and rebuild but the classes still weren't there.  As soon as I debugged the project (Tomcat Dynamic Web project) eclipse copied the missing jars into the below folder.  I don't understand how, why or when they are being deleted.

MYWORKSPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\myproject\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Sio I ran Eclipse multiple times during the day and the project libs were fine.  I just ran in it after about 4+ hours and when I debug the project 3 AWS specific libs were deleted from Tomcat's compiled Web-INF\lib folder causing the error.  The only thing different about these libs and the dozen others in the project that don't get delete is that they are referenced from a sub-folder.  I've moved them out into the general population to see what happens.

Comment: This is very strange.  Seems there's some time limit on the delete.  I moved the jars into the common area and debugged fine.  Next day, sure enough Eclipse deleted just the 3 libs specified in 1 user library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turns out to be a deployment assembly problem in that the missing libs were not explicitly exported when the dynamic web app was deployed. Once I added the libs (Project properties | Deployment Assembly) the app runs every time.  How, when and why they were sometimes deployed, other times deleted and always generated a working war file remains a mystery to me.  But the debugging is solid now.